# Delete specific row in dynamically generated gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a small GridView that will hold certain items. This is the code that generates the gridview after a user clicks an item:

```
 if (grdCarritoAddons.Rows.Count == 0)
        {

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(System.String)));
        }
        else
        {
            dt = HttpContext.Current.Session["DataTable"] as DataTable;
        }
        Session["DataTable"] = dt;

        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = AddonName.ToString();
        dr1[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceAddon);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        grdCarritoAddons.DataSource = dt;
        grdCarritoAddons.DataBind();

    }
```

Now I need a user to be able to select an item and delete a specific one. In the ASPX page I already added the Delete Command and created an empty RowDeleting method in code and on the GridView properties. It isn't working, and I came up with a solution that somewhat works but isn't what I need to do. It basically wipes out the whole DataTable.

```
            //grdCarritoAddons.DataSource = dt;
        //grdCarritoAddons.DataBind();
        //Session["DataTable"] = dt;
        //Session.Remove("Total");
```

I tried this:

```
grdCarritoAddons.Rows.RemoveAt(grdCarritoAddons.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

But no go. Doesn't work in ASP. Thanks for any help :)

Current Code:

```
            dt = HttpContext.Current.Session["DataTable"] as DataTable;
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(grdCarritoAddons.SelectedRow.RowIndex);
```

But its throwing an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception. If I put an IF to check if the row is null it won't execute at all... but the data is obviously not empty.

Comment: _"Doesn't work in ASP"_ What does that mean, do you get an exception or an undesired result? What happens exactly?

Comment: This is the Error: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt' and no extension method 'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, this method does not exist as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). You should modify the datasource instead and databind the grid afterwards. `DataRowCollection` has a [`RemoveAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the Error: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt' and no extension method
>   'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found

Yes, this method does not exist as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should modify the datasource instead and databind the grid afterwards. `DataRowCollection` has a [`RemoveAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(grdCarritoAddons.SelectedRow.RowIndex);
grdCarritoAddons.DataSource = dt;
grdCarritoAddons.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hey Tim. I was working with something similar, but I went ahead and used the code you posted. It is throwing me an Error in the IDE, says Gridview does not contain a definition for SelectedRows.

Comment: @LordRelix: the ASP.NET GridView does not support multiple selected rows. The property is [`SelectedRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx) and a `GridViewRow` has a `RowIndex` property instead. Edited my answer.

Comment: It seems to be registering the column as null. It throws a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. If I input 'if ((row != null))' it won't execute and there will be no error. Weird. I tried loading the DT beforehand in code just in case. I will update the code in the OP.

Comment: @LordRelix: which _column_, do you mean _row_ instead? If so, which row do you mean, what is `null`? Use the debugger. Is the `DataTable` null?

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot. I figured it out. That line cannot run under "RowDeleting" but under "SelectedIndexChanged". RowDeleting was throwing that exception but the same code (and then saving to the DT and Databinding) in SelectedIndexChanged worked perfectly. Thanks a million.