# Delete from gridview using checkbox Asp.net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use checkbox to remove items from a gridview but I had this and removes every item.

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(GridView2.DataSource);
            data.Rows.RemoveAt(GridView2.Rows.Count - 1);
            data.AcceptChanges();
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
```

Then I'm trying this

```
for (int i = GridView2.SelectedRow.Count - 1; -1 < i; i--)
        {
            object objChecked = GridView2.SelectedRow[i].Cells[0].Value;
            if ((objChecked != null) && !(bool)objChecked)
            {
                GridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
```

**These are the errors I'm getting**

- Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and
  'int'
- Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 
  '
- GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt'
  and no extension method 'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type
  'GridViewRowCollection' could be found(are you missing a using
  directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major issues:

1) [`GridView.SelectedRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a collection property, it is a standard property. Therefore, you can neither use `Count` property nor array index on it. To iterate between rows with `for` loop, use [`GridView.Rows.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // do something
}
```

2) `RemoveAt` method doesn't exist in `GridViewRowCollection` method, you can see that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to delete rows with selected index from data source and rebind to `GridView` afterwards.

Hence, use a `foreach` loop to iterate grid rows and put a check against `Checked` property of each checkbox as given by example below.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("CheckBoxName") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
        // delete from data source (e.g. DataTable), not GridView row
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);

        // you can execute delete query against DB here
    }
}

// rebind the grid
GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Similar issues:

[delete multiple rows in gridview using checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131532/delete-multiple-rows-in-gridview-using-checkboxes)

[Delete specific row in dynamically generated gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270100/delete-specific-row-in-dynamically-generated-gridview)

Comment: ok thanks for this info however when I add this  CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("CheckBoxName") as CheckBox; and check a row it is saying that it is null

Comment: And it still removing all the items that weren't check and if I check all it says that there's  no row at position 1